# Запретить юзеру ходить по запрещенным маршрутам

Tags: angular2

На корневом маршруте стоит `resolver`, который дергает сервисы для получения прав пользователей.

Эти права я далее использую для отрисовки меню, но ничего не мешает пользователю ввести маршрут ручками.

Читал про Guard, которые по описанию похожи на решение моей проблемы.

Однако, если верить ресурсам, то `Guard` срабатывает раньше, чем `Resolver` => на момент срабатывания `Guard` я не смогу располагать правами.

Переносить логику инициализации из `Resolver` в `Guard` по моему не правильно, ведь `Resolver` как раз и создан для задач получения данных.

Собственно, а как правильно сделать?

Ну и еще небольшой вопрос:

На сколько `Guard` вообще надежен? Ведь по идее, юзер может поправить JS в браузере и свободно гулять. Нет?

Answer (score 0):

**[canAvtivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate)** - это защита маршрутизатора, которая выполняется для проверки, должен ли маршрутизатор перейти по данному пути.

**[Resolver](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve)** является поставщиком данных, который выбирает данные для компонента **до** того, как маршрутизатор начинает навигацию.

В принципе так как Вы получаете данные возможно стоить использовать только resolver.

Что касается надежности, так js конечно же не надежен. Вы просто не пропускаете на конкретный урл. Это всеголишь защита от дурака. Дополнительно нужно проверять доступ еще и на бэке. Например, использовать JWT токен.

---

Небольшой [пример](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20routes%3A%20Routes%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20path%3A%20''%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20resolve%3A%20%5BSomeGlobalResolverForAllPaths%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20children%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20path%3A%20''%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20loadChildren%3A%20'.%2Fhome...'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20path%3A%20'blog'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20canActivate%3A%20%5BAuthGuardService%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20loadChildren%3A%20'.%2Fblog...'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FResolver%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%0D%0A%0D%0A%40Injectable()%0D%0Aexport%20class%20SomeGlobalResolverForAllPaths%20implements%20Resolve%3CObservable%3Cstring%3E%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(private%20UserService)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20resolve()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20someData%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20UserService.getData(someData).subscribe(...)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FCanActivate%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%0D%0A%0D%0A%40Injectable()%0D%0Aexport%20class%20AuthGuardService%20implements%20CanActivate%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20user%3A%20UserService%2C%20private%20router%3A%20Router)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20canActivate(route%3A%20ActivatedRouteSnapshot%2C%20state%3A%20RouterStateSnapshot)%3A%20Observable%3Cboolean%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20user.getData().pipe(%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20map(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20res%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(res)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20true%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.router.navigate(%5B'home'%5D)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20false%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FUserService%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%0D%0A%40Injectable()%0D%0Aclass%20UserService%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20public%20data%24%3A%20Observable%3Cany%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20protected%20cache%24%3A%20Observable%3CArray%3Cany%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20http%3A%20HttpClient)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20public%20getData(data%3F%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20options%3A%20any%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20data%3A%20data%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20request%24%20%3D%20this.http.get(%60url%60%2C%20options)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.httpSenderWithCache(request%24%2C%205000)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20protected%20expireCache(time%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20cacheCleaner%24%20%3D%20interval(time).pipe(take(1))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20cacheCleaner%24.subscribe(_%20%3D%3E%20this.cache%24%20%3D%20null)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20protected%20httpSenderWithCache(service%3A%20Observable%3Cany%3E%2C%20time%3A%20number)%3A%20Observable%3Cany%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(!this.cache%24)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.expireCache(time)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.cache%24%20%3D%20service.pipe(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20shareReplay(1)%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20catchError((err)%20%3D%3E%20this.catchError(err))%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.cache%24%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D) так, что бы понять принцип, с кэшированием ответа по времени. *Там можно убрать `expireCache` и время и будете пользоваться 1м результатом в течении сеанса.*

Comment: Да, но тем не менее, мне на основании этих данных нужно понимать пускать юзера или нет.

Comment: 1 Вы можете проанализировать их и редиректить на другой урл уже в резолвере. 2 Вы можете отбрабатывать их в canActivate (использовать как Subject)

Comment: например есть урл main/a main/b- допстим на  урл main/b должен попать только авторизированный пользователь. Вы на main/b вешаете резолвер, получаете данные, обрабатываете их и редиректите на main/a в случае если не авторизирован

Comment: а, у Вас 1 резолвер на все приложение. Ну тогда используте дополнительно canActivate

Comment: добавил небольшой пример