# Дочерний CanActivate срабатывает раньше корневого Resolver

Tags: angular2

В общем есть такая конфигурация:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: BaseComponent, resolve: { data: PermissionResolver }, children: [
      {
        path: '', loadChildren: './area/Home/Home.module#HomeModule',
      }
}
```

Внутри модуля Home такой роут:

```
const homeRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'home', component: homeContainerComponent, children: [
      {
        path: 'add', component: AddContainerComponent, canActivate: [CanActivateAdd], children: [
          {
            path: '', component: AddComponent
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
  }
];
```

Так вот, когда я сразу иду на home/add через адресную строку, то Resolve не срабатывает, а срабатывает сразу же canActive.

Вообще я ожидал, что Guard'ы будут срабатывать в иерархическом порядке.

Т.е сначала Resolve, так как он висит в корневом маршруте, а потом уже все дочерние Guard'ы.

Как добиться желаемого? Т.е сначала получить учетные данные от API в независимости куда пользователь зашел, а затем использовать canActive?

Нашел только вот [такую](https://webformyself.com/problemy-zashhity-routa-v-angular/) статейку, как из ресолвера делают canActive. Неужели нет методов "из коробки"?

Comment: а почему на каждый чилдовый роутер не повесить резолвер вместо родительского?

Comment: А зачем резолвить каждый маршрут? Имхо, процесс должен быть выполнен 1 раз в корне.

Comment: не совсем так. Каждый роут - это независимая сущность. Я могу написать example.com/test а могу example.com/home и в каждом случае должен быть свой резолвер. Другое дело, что данные должны скачиваться 1 только раз. Так в предыдущем вопросе я показывал как закешировать результат

Comment: Для этого нужено использовать rxjs. (Тут)[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/982062/Запретить-юзеру-ходить-по-запрещенным-маршрутам/982174] добавлял пример с использованием rxjs `shareReplay`

Comment: @KostiantynOkhotnyk не сочтите за грубость, но по вашему ответу и примеру кода с `Resolve<Observable<string>>` и `return UserService.getData(someData).subscribe(...);` - я вижу, что вы понятия не имеете для чего используются резолверы и как они работают

Comment: @overthesanity используются для предзагрузки данных в компоненте. Вы как -то по другому используете? И в  чем собственно  проблема? В Resolve<Observable<string>> и сабскрайбе? Так я отладкой не занимался

Comment: @iluxa1810 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bovd6k

Comment: @KostiantynOkhotnyk люди которые используют резолверы и знают как с ними работать никогда не напишут `Resolve<Observable<string>>` и `return subscribe(...)`, сори

Comment: @overthesanity Т.е в этом случае я инициализирую свой сервис до canActive?

Comment: @overthesanity классно, работает. Можете ответом? Получается, что аутентификацию нужно грузить при инициализации?

Comment: @iluxa1810 для меня достаточно что у тебя заработало :) я не фармлю очки